# Floated element is coming below, instead of to side

Tags: html, css, css-float, sidebar

I'm not sure what code is causing this problem, hence I would ask that you view the [live site](http://dev.foracure.org.au/) please.

The sidebar `#widgets` is not level with the top of `#content`. It is about 1430px below being level with `#content`, and Chrome inspector shows no margin, padding that is causing this.

Can you see the problem?

Comment: Could you make the title a little more specific please?

Comment: it will get at top of the node before it, so you can wrap all your `.sticky` into a single element, and leave your `#widget` beside this container element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `#widgets` element **BEFORE** `#content`.

[image]

This behavior is being caused by floats. As a general rule, place the element to be floated before the "main" element to be wrapped around the float. To simplify somewhat, `float` takes the element, removes it from the normal flow, places it in the specified location, then renders the **following** elements around the floated element.

By the time `#content` has rendered, it's too late to float something inside or beside it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks torazaburo. That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

One quick fix I can think of is setting the position to `absolute`, and setting `right` to about `10px`, in the css of `#widgets`:

```
#widgets {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
}
```

Which yields:

[image]